# Changing SpriteKit Game Background At A Certain Score

Tags: ios

I'm having a little trouble implementing a background change when the player hits a certain score.

I'm using the if(self.score>=10) line to tell my game to change the background but it doesn't seem to be working. I have no errors with this line but no results either.

What I have:

```
@implementation Scene{
SKScrollingNode * floor;
SKScrollingNode * back;
SKLabelNode * scoreLabel;   
}

- (void) createBackground
{
   back = [SKScrollingNode scrollingNodeWithImageNamed:@"back" inContainerWidth:WIDTH(self)];

   if(self.score>=10){ 
   back = [SKScrollingNode scrollingNodeWithImageNamed:@"image2" inContainerWidth:WIDTH(self)];

   [back setAnchorPoint:CGPointZero];
   [back setPhysicsBody:[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame]];
   back.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = backBitMask;
   back.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = birdBitMask;
   [self addChild:back];
}
```

Comment: how often you call the createbackground? Did you checked your score (NSLog)? I would set KVO on score and when it changes I would then set new background.

Comment: Hmm...ok I will try that now.

Answer (score 0):

there are certain points you have to keep in your mind i think your both background contains physics body

1)may be and the time of transition they first background colliding with second background and they preventing each other to swap

change your collisionBitMask for both background ->prevent them for colliding

for eg

```
 bg.physicsBody.categoryBitMask=bg1;
 bg.physicsBody.collisionBitMask=0;
 bg.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask=bg2;

 bg.physicsBody.categoryBitMask=bg2;
 bg.physicsBody.collisionBitMask=0;
 bg.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask=bg1;
```

or use skaction to swap backgrounds

Answer (score 0):

The way i would do this would be to create a brand new SKScene entirely with a new background.

Or if you want them to scroll to the next background. I would create two backgrounds.

Ex. 
                                 //this syntax is wrong (dont remember)

> ```
> //initializing
> SKSpriteNode *bg1 = [SKSpritenode spritenodefromImage:@"bg1"];
> SKSpriteNode *bg1 = [SKSpritenode spritenodefromImage:@"bg1"];
>
> bg1.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);
> bg2.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2 + bg1.size.width, self.size.height/2);
>
> //////////////////////////////
>
> //then when you want to scroll them
> -(void)scrollBackgrounds
> {
>     bg1.position = CGPointMake(bg1.position.x - 5, self.size.height/2);
> bg2.position = CGPointMake(bg2.position.x -5 , self.size.height/2);
>
> }
> ```